# использование контейнера map

Tags: c++

как я могу реализовать такую конструкцию ?

```
map<string,map<string,map<string,string>>> = 
{ 
   {"B",{"C",{"G","I"}}}
};
```

не получается, компилятор ругается, а мне нужно именно, чтобы был ключ "B", у которого значение является тоже ключом "C", чье значение в свою очередь тоже ключ "G" , у которого есть вот конечное значение "I"

Answer (score 2):

Можно, главное переменную указать и чуточку больше скобочек поставить

```
map<string,map<string,map<string,string>>> x = 
{ 
   {{"B",{{"C",{{"G","I"}}}}}}
};
```

Comment: А почему не получается записать несколько таких значений?
 map <string,map<string,map<string,string>>> A = 
 {
  {{"B",{{"C",{{"G","I"}}}}}},
  {{"B",{{"C",{{"H","I"}}}}}}
 };

Comment: скобочки нужно правильно расставлять `{ 
     {
         {"B",{{"C",{{"G","I"}}}}},
         {"B",{{"C",{{"H","I"}}}}}
    }
};`